# multi-touch and windows 7

Tags: windows-7

If I buy multi-touch monitor like(Samsung MULTITOUCH LD220Z) Then can i move multiple windows(minimize close) control multiple volume sliders simultaneously in audio mixer and does all this extends to other non win7 native application like (Cubase Ableton live and so ... )?

Answer (score 1):

> - Yes you will be able to to move multiple windows(minimize close)
>     ,control multiple volume sliders
>     simultaneously in audio mixer etc
> - Other windows supports touch-screen but not multi-touch screen
> - Compared to other earlier windows, Windows 7 features multi-touch
>     technology where you can control
>     windows elements with multiple
>     fingers.

*For more Information go to* http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/touch